# Banach Algebra Isomorphism

Tags: group-isomorphism, banach-algebras, gelfand-representation

Let $X=l^1$ with coordinate multiplication - it is commutative Banach algebra without unit. The Gelfand transformation is defined as $\widehat{x}(e_n)=x_n$ for $x \in l^1$. I would like to prove, that this algebra is isomorphic to $C^*$-algebra. Any ideas ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely not, even as a Banach space. Commutative C*-algebras are isomorphic to $C_0(X)$ for some locally compact Hausdorff space, which is infinite when the algebra is infinite-dimensional. In such case, you will find a subalgebra isomorphic to $c_0$. The space $c_0$ does not embed isomorphically into $\ell_1$ because the latter space is weakly sequentially complete.

Actually, it is easy to see that $\ell_1$ does not satisfy the C*-condition under the original norm. Take $x=e_1 + e_2$. Then $xx^* = x$ but $\|xx^*\|=2\neq \|x\|^2$. (In other words, observe that non-zero self-adjoint projections in C*-algebras have norm 1.)

Comment: Is it hold for general $l^p$ space for finite $p$ ?

Comment: @lojdmoj, yes. Why don't you try to modify my arguments to see that?

Comment: Well, $l^1$ does not satisfy the $C^{*}$-condition, but I would like to show, that there is no isomorphism between $l^{1}$ algebra and $C^{*}$ algebra. We have that $C_{0}(l^{1})=c_0$ but $c_0$ does not embed isomorphically into $l^{1}$. Is is true, that $C_{0}(l^{p})=c_0$ for $p>1$ ?

Comment: @lodmoj, I have a feeling that you don't read my answers. I've shown that there is even no linear isomorphism between $\ell_1$ and a C*-algebra...

Comment: Yes, but I am confused. I still do not understand if algebra $l^p$ is isomorphic to $C^{*}$ algebra.

Comment: @lojdmoj, an infinite-dimensional C*-algebra contains a sequence of pairwise orthogonal positive unit vectors that, by the spectral theorem, span a subspace isometric to $c_0$. The Banach space $c_0$ does not linearly embed into $\ell_p$...